# Show progress on Ui

Tags: delphi

I have a simple application. One Form and one DataModule.
I have some process in DataModule and want to show progress (using progress bar) in UI.

what is the best approach?

Comment: It depends, what exactly is happening in the Data Module?

Comment: @JerryDodge, I have a few loops for updating data.

Comment: Define "best" objectively, by what criteria?  Meanwhile -1.   The best approach imo, other things being equal,  is not to execute the datamodule process in the gui (VCL) thread but ymmv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is define an Event on your datamodule and then implement a handler for the event in your form and assign it to datamodule event. 
Then, in your process, you invoke the event and thereby call the event handler.

Something like this:

```
type
  TMyProgressEvent = procedure (Position, TotalSteps: Integer; Msg: string) of object

TMyDM = class
private
  FOnProgress: TMyProgressEvent;
....
....
public
  procedure UpdateCustomerOrders;
  property OnProgress: TMyProgressEvent read FOnProgress write FOnProgress;
end

TMyForm = class
....
....
  // you can change the position or progress bar here
  // or if you want to log 
  procedure MyFormProress(Position, TotalSteps: Integer; Msg: string);
end
```

Your TMyDM.UpdateCustomerOrders may look like this:

```
 procedure TMyDM.UpdateCustomerOrders()
 begin
   for I = 1 to 10 do 
   begin
     ... 
     ... you are processing something 
     ...
     //call event like this
     FOnProgress(I, 12, 'looping');
   end;
   .... another process here
   FOnProgress(11, 12, 'another process');

   .... one more process here
   FOnProgress(12, 12, 'process finished');
 end;
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the q.  It presupposes that something on the datamodule generates the events, yet how to do that is exactly what the OP seems to be asking.

Comment: @MartynA, In this approach, DM (datamodule), call the event. the Event is assigned by the method in form.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, of course. But what decides when the datamodule invokes the event?

Comment: As OP mentioned, some process happens in DM. it might be a loop, or consequent database operation. DM can call the event, in loop or after each operation. I think is very clear. I edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Well,  you may think it is very clear, but the reason I posted my comments was in the hope of making yours a better answer.  Atm, it merely moves the problem, not solves it.  You obviously know the answer, istm, but need to explain it better, imo.

Comment: @MartynA, Thank you. I believe I had to have more detail. I edited my answer. I'm very new here :)

Comment: Yes, that is much better, +1.  Remember these qs and as are not just for the benefit of the particular person who posted the q.  The main value of SO is that future readers of different levels of programming and language skills can benefit, too.

Comment: I figured out how your code works. I tried and worked well for me. Thank you

Comment: I edited your answer to follow more standard conventions. In fact, your property was following some convention I've never seen before, and I'm not sure if it would even compile or not. It seemed to be mixing a property with a procedure.